# What would be the type of item in MVC4 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-3-areas, razor-declarative-helpers

I am using webgrid to displat list of records.

My view is tightly coupled with IEnumerable.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.SitesConfig.Configuration>
```

I am binding webgrid with Model.

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 50);
```

I am trying to format a column using @helper method. @helper method taking a parametr of type Models.SitesConfig.Configuration.

When I try to load the view, I am getting invalid arguments error.

This is my view.

```
    @model IEnumerable<Models.SitesConfig.SiteConfiguration>
@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SatelliteSite.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Satellite Sites";
}
@helper FormatTemplateColors(Models.SitesConfig.SiteConfiguration item)
{
    @String.Format(
        "Border: {0} <br/>Link: {1} <br/>Text: {2}",
        item.BorderColor != null ? item.BorderColor.Name : string.Empty,
        item.LinkColor != null ? item.LinkColor.Name : string.Empty,
        item.TextColor != null ? item.TextColor.Name : string.Empty)
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 50);
}
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Template", 
            style: "color-column-width", 
            format:(item) => @FormatTemplateColors(item)
        )
         )
</div>
```

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: Can you format the code a little better to make it readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `format` lambda the `item` parameter is an instance of the [WebGridRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridrow%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class (in a form of `dynamic`) where the `Value` property holds the actual item.

So you need to write:

```
format:(item) => @FormatTemplateColors(item.Value)
```

SideNote if you wan't to output html you need to use the `Html.Raw` helper. So modify your helper to:

```
@helper FormatTemplateColors(Models.SitesConfig.SiteConfiguration item)
{
    @Html.Raw(String.Format(...
}
```